# How to dynamically change the annotation value in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am using **chartjs-plugin-annotation** and **chartjs-plugin-draggable** in my **chart.js** project. When I changed the value of an annotation which draws a vertical line and tried updating the chart the line remains unchanged in its position. But I can see the value being updated in the chart object.

Comment: found the solution..need to destroy the chart and create new chart

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still lands here by googling: It's a bug. As a workaround you can remove the ID from your annotation but that might break mouse events. More info [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/issues/88).

Answer (score 0):

call chart-plugin-annotation updated values through function by passing parameters that you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me. I'm using a separate function to set the new value and text label then call the chart.update() method. works fine for me.
see [chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-options) on updating charts and its options.

```
options: { // chart.js options object

...

annotation: {
              annotations: [
                {
                  type: 'line',
                  mode: 'horizontal',
                  scaleID: 'y-percent',
                  value: 0,
                  borderColor: 'rgba(238, 68, 226,0.2)',
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderDash: [5,5],
                  label: {
                    enabled: true,
                    content: 'Your text label ',
                    position: 'end',
                    drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(238, 68, 226,0.4)'
                  }
              },
              
          
              ]
            }, // annotation
} // options

setAnnotationValue(val){
      chart.options.annotation.annotations[0].value = val; // set the Value
      chart.options.annotation.annotations[0].label.content += " "+ val + "%"; // append the value to the label (if applicable)
      chart.update(); // and finally update the chart.
    },
```